# JS addElementAndSubmitForm() function gone from the web

Tags: javascript, forms, addition, element

I'm working on a website again after a few years. I'm sure it wasn't me who had written this script below so I'm trying to find the source but I simply can't. My guess is that it was removed for a reason (obsolete?). Can someone have a look please if the function (I hope the name speaks for itself) should work anyway?

```
function addElementAndSubmitForm(formName,actionUrl,elName,elValue) {
    var form = document.forms[formName];
    form.action = actionUrl;
    var el = document.createElement("input");
    el.type = "hidden";
    el.name = elName;
    el.value = elValue;
    form.appendChild(el);
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addElementAndSubmitForm(formName,actionUrl,elName,elValue) {
    var form = document.forms[formName];
    form.action = actionUrl;
    var el = document.createElement("input");
    el.type = "hidden";
    el.name = elName;
    el.value = elValue;
    form.appendChild(el);
    form.submit();
}

addElementAndSubmitForm('myform','#','some','value');
```

```html
<form id='myform'></form>
```

The function `addElementAndSubmitForm` takes 4 arguments and adds a hidden input element to the form.

The first argument `formName` is used to select the form it is the id of the form.

The second argument `actionUrl` is the action url of the form.

The third argument `elName` is value of the name attribute of the input.

The fourth argument `value` is value of the value attribute of the input.

Here I have a form

```
<form id='myform'></form>
```

and I am calling the method as follows,

```
addElementAndSubmitForm('myform','#','some','value');
```

which will add add hidden input field  inside the form

`<input type="hidden" name="some" value="value">`

inside the form with id `myform`.

Comment: Care to explain please.

Comment: Thanks, actually, I know what it's supposed to do but for some reason no variable is passed with the form and I thought maybe the code is obsolete. But if the script is valid I guess I need to debug somewhere else then.

Comment: Yes, the function is doing what it is supposed to do. You can share other related parts of the code. we could help.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer but I'm too low on reputations so it won't be shown. There are a dozen included PHP files having my suspicion so I'm trying to find the problem myself first :)

Comment: You know your method calling actually worked. Before it was
'<?php echo WEB_ROOT.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'
Replacing it with hash did the trick. Which is strange because I only changed the domain.